# Mongoose: How to update nested fields with fields present in request body only?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Looking to update lookupSchema **images** nested fields

```
var lookupSchema = new Schema({
    images:{
      "img1":String,
      "img2":String,
      "img3":String,
      "img4":String
    }
 }
```

As I don't know which fields are available in request body during **findOneAndUpdate** operation, I am unable to assign like this

```
$set: { 
    'images.img1':  req.body.img1, 
    'images.img2':  req.body.img2,
    'images.img3':  req.body.img3
}
```

If I code like above and specify all fields, already available fields become empty after **update** due to unavailable fields in request.

Need something like this to update available fields

```
$set: { "images.$[element]" : req.body  }
```

I have searched a lot but unable to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create a function like below to be able to achieve your result.

```
function update() {
   let temp = {};
   for(let field in req.body) {
   temp["images."+field] = req.body[field];
   }

  db.collection.findOneAndUpdate({._id:...},{$set:temp},{upsert:true},function(err,result)
  {...});
  }
```

Comment: solved my problem. Should I need to set upsert as true ?